# How to use count with null-resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have defined a `null resource` which looks as below:

```
resource "null_resource" "mynull-resource" {
  triggers = {
    always-update =  timestamp()
  }

  # Connection Block for Provisioners to connect to EC2 Instance
  connection {
    type = "ssh"
    host = aws_instance.web[count.index].public_ip  #Giving error
    user = "ec2-user"
    password = ""
    private_key = file("ec2keypair.pem")
  }
```

**Error:**

```
 The "count" object can only be used in "module", "resource", and "data" blocks, and only when the "count" argument is set.
```

How can I update the `connection block` to connect to multiple hosts?

I have tried using `spat operator` but it is not working `host = aws_instance.web.*.public_ip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `count`  under `resource`:

```
resource "null_resource" "mynull-resource" {

  count = length(aws_instance.web)
 
  triggers = {
    always-update =  timestamp()
  }

  # Connection Block for Provisioners to connect to EC2 Instance
  connection {
    type = "ssh"
    host = aws_instance.web[count.index].public_ip  #Giving error
    user = "ec2-user"
    password = ""
    private_key = file("ec2keypair.pem")
  }
```